# Force Docker Container to wait until Postgresql container is ready

Tags: javascript, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, postgresql-9.1

Consider the Dockerfile :

**Dockerfile :**

```
FROM node:14
COPY . /app
RUN npm i
RUN npm run build_database_migrations <<<<====== This is the problematic command

... more commands
```

Which uses `sequelize-cli` :

**In package.json :**

```
"scripts": {
   "build_database_migrations": "sequelize db:migrate", 
  }
```

And the Docker-compose :

**Docker-compose.yaml**

```
version: "3"
services:
  
  postgresql:
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: user1
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pass1
      POSTGRES_DB: somedb      
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
 
  app:    
    build:
      context: ./employee
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:    
      - postgresql      
    links:
      - postgresql
```

Whenever I run the `Docker-compose up` the `app` never waits for `postgresql` to be up and running ,
which results in building the `app` container and running the command `RUN npm run build_database_migrations` before the Postgreqsql Container is listening on port `5432`.

How can we force the `app` Container to wait until `Postreqsql` container is ready and listening on port `5432` , so it would be able to run the migrations on a live Postgresql Container ?

Comment: You could have a "prebuild_database_migrations" script that uses e.g. wait-on to wait for the port to be available. But I don't think the database would ever be available during the *build* phase, you should migrate at the start of the *run* phase.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I have them , but I want to run them automatically once the DB container is ready.How do we do that ?

Comment: You have *what*? Again I don't think the DB will *ever* be available during the build phase defined in the Dockerfile.

Comment: I flagged this as a duplicate of the canonical question about one Compose-managed container waiting for another; but @jonrsharpe is right, regardless of that, your image build can _never_ talk to the database (among other things it will not be attached to the Compose network).